# How to get SAM activation tickets (iPhone 5, iOS 7.0.4)

Tags: ios, iphone, unlock

I was asked to unlock an iPhone 5. The phone has been jailbroken successfuly (with SSH access), but I can't get around the simlock.

I've tried SAM, but with no luck. When SAM is enabled, the phone seems to log into the network with any valid microSIM, but it does not work at all: Data do not work, calling makes "call failed" error message. The phone does not receive the SMS message I've sent.

So, I've tried to search a way specific for iPhone 5 and iOS 7.0.4. [This one](http://maypalo.com/2013/12/27/unlock-iphone-ios-7/) looks promising (although iPhone 5 was not mentioned explicitly). However, there is a prerequisite:

> You must have SAM activation tickets for this guide to work.

How can I get them?

If I can't, is there another way around, except downgrade to iOS 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sAM tickets were only available for a week on April 2012. Apple was able to patch the servers at that time but a lot of iPhone 4 users waiting for the 4.11.015 baseband unlock was able to get it. sAM doesn't work on iPhone higher than 4 since this is the only iPhone available in April 2012 . Don't assume it will work for the iPhone 5 since you need a ticket that is no longer available